# Knapsack Backtracking Using only O(W) space

Tags: c++, optimization, backtracking, knapsack-problem

So I have this code that I have written that correctly finds the optimal value for the knapsack problem.

```
int mat[2][size + 1];
memset(mat, 0, sizeof(mat));

int i = 0;
while(i < nItems)
{
    int j = 0;
    if(i % 2 != 0)
    {
        while(++j <= size)
        {
            if(weights[i] <= j) mat[1][j] = max(values[i] + mat[0][j - weights[i]], mat[0][j]);
            else mat[1][j] = mat[0][j];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(++j <= size)
        {
            if(weights[i] <= j) mat[0][j] = max(values[i] + mat[1][j - weights[i]], mat[1][j]);
            else mat[0][j] = mat[1][j];
        }
    }
    i++;
}
int val = (nItems % 2 != 0)? mat[0][size] : mat[1][size];
cout << val << endl;
return 0;
```

This part I udnerstand.  However I am trying to keep the same memory space, i.e. O(W), but also now compute the optimal solution using backtracking.  This is where I am finding trouble.  The hints I have been given is this

```
Now suppose that we also want the optimal set of items. Recall that the goal                                                         

in ﬁnding the optimal solution in part 1 is to ﬁnd the optimal path from 

entry K(0,0) to entry K(W,n). The optimal path must pass through an 

intermediate node (k,n/2) for some k; this k corresponds to the remaining 

capacity in the knapsack of the optimal solution after items n/2 + 1,...n 

have been considered
```

The question asked is this.

```
Implement a modiﬁed version of the algorithm from part 2 that returns not 
only the optimal value, but also the remaining capacity of the optimal 
solution after the last half of items have been considered
```

Any help would be apprecaited to get me started.  Thanks